ITurnContext moved after update Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.Core" Version="4.22.4", from 4.21.1
The type 'ITurnContext' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Microsoft.Bot.Builder, Version=4.21.1.0,
Adding the suggested reference doesnt resolve the issue. Will register with Microsoft, in the meantime have rolled back to 4.21

Is this issue resolved? I have below installed.



